# How can I disable Photos Agent on High Sierra (10.13.4)?

Tags: high-sierra, photos.app, services

Looks like Photos Agent is running in the background. I'd like to dedicate this machine to file services and not run unnecessary processes. How can I disable "Photos Agent" at boot time. I'm hoping to free up resources like RAM and CPU.

Answer (score 2):

From personal experience, I can say that letting it finish once (it processes photos in the Photos app) makes it end forever.

But you can speed up that process by removing iCloud photos syncing.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder about iCloud Photos. This was the culprit. I hadn't loaded any photos into Photo.app.

Comment: However, this is not a perfect solution, because it relies on reasonable user behavior, rather than taking control of the system feature, at the admin level.

Comment: Absolutely this isn't perfect. Depending of your needs, you may want to take control of all iCloud and other user friendly processes that may interfere with your file services needs. One of the answers I found looking around was killing the unnecessary deamons.